# Is there any point in arriving before 6:30 am at Buenos Aires terminal when taking the 7:15 am Buquebus boat service to Montevideo?

Tags: argentina, sea-travel, buenos-aires, uruguay, montevideo

I plan to take the 7:15 am Buquebus boat service from Buenos Aires to Montevideo.

https://www.buquebus.com/english/faq says:

> The Buenos Aires terminal is open Monday to Monday from 6:30am till 23:30pm all year
>
> [...]
>
> It is highly recommended to be 2 hours prior the departure of the ship to make the Check In, migrations and boarding. If you are travelling with a car, it is imperative to be at the Terminal 2hs before departure because the cars must be loaded before passengers. It is important to take into account that in high peak seasons all the processes can take longer than expected.

The first paragraph says that the Buenos Aires terminal is closed before 6:30 am but the last paragraph says it is recommended to arrive two hours prior to the departure time of the boat.

Is there any point in showing up before 6:30 am at Buenos Aires terminal when taking the 7:15 am Buquebus boat service from Buenos Aires to Montevideo? (e.g., clearing the immigration before boarding, if the immigration counter is open).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so. This terminal is indeed structured like an airport, with check-in and stuff, but there is fewer hassles - not that much of security theatre, boarding is faster, boats don't need time to steer around like planes do, etc. I think 45 minutes is more than enough to board the ship, I don't think they are leaving without you.